# Responsive Popup Window Doesn't Scroll To Bottom So It Can Be Closed

Tags: javascript, scroll, popup, window, responsive

I'm using a popup window from https://codepen.io/pedrobenoit91/pen/aJGzYg and have been able to tweak it get it to be responsive. Here is my test page: [Responsive Popup Window Test](https://cismiami.org/index3.html) Here's the tweaked coding I've used:

HTML5 Page

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/popupwindow.js"></script>
<div class='popup'>
<div class='popwin'>
<span style="font-size:1.50em; color:#2e5c9d;">CIS Miami Is Here for Our Students &amp; Families</span>
<p>
<a href="/covid19.html">See what we're doing and view resources &#187;</a>
<br> 
COVID-19 is impacting our students and families in ways that no one could have possibly imagined. Communities In Schools of Miami remains dedicated to ensuring all
of our students and families have the crucial resources they urgently need at this time, but we can't do it without you.
<br>
blah<br>
blah<br>
blah<br>
blah<br>
blah<br>
blah<br>
blah<br>
blah<br>
blah<br>
blah<br>

  <div style="display:block; padding:0.50em 0;">
  <div class="btnOrange"><a class="btn" href="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_s-xclick&hosted_button_id=SDSKUTE5VQXCW&source=url"><b>DONATE TO CIS MIAMI <i class="fas fa-angle-double-right"></i></b></a></div>
  </div>
<div class="right"><a href='' class='close closepop'><i class="fas fa-times"></i> CLOSE</a></div>
</p>
</div>
</div>
```

SCRIPT

```
$(function(){
var overlay = $('<div id="overlay"></div>');
overlay.show();
overlay.appendTo(document.body);
$('.popup').show();
$('.close').click(function(){
$('.popup').hide();
overlay.appendTo(document.body).remove();
return false;
});

$('.x').click(function(){
$('.popup').hide();
overlay.appendTo(document.body).remove();
return false;
});
});
```

STYLESHEET

```
#overlay { position:fixed; top:0; left:0; width:100%; height:100%; background-color:#000;
  filter:alpha(opacity=70); -moz-opacity:0.7; -khtml-opacity:0.7; opacity:0.7; z-index:100; display:none; }
.popup { width:100%; margin:0 auto; display:none; position:fixed; top:0; left:0; z-index:101; } /* Added top and left for positioning */
.popwin { min-width:90%; width:90%; min-height:150px; margin:2.0em auto; background:#fff; position:relative; 
  z-index:103; padding:0.5em 1.0em; border-radius:5px; box-shadow:0 2px 5px #000; } /* Changed with to percentages for responsive. Margin determines height from top */
.popwin p { clear:both; color:#555555; /* text-align:justify; */ font-size:1.2em; font-family:sans-serif; }
.popwin a { text-decoration:none; }
.popwin p a { color:#d91900; font-weight:bold; }
.popwin .x { float:right; height:35px; left:0px; position:relative; top:-25px; width:34px; }
.popwin .x:hover { cursor:pointer; }

a.closepop:link, a.closepop:visited, a.closepop:active { text-decoration:none; color:#444; }
a.closepop:hover { color:#444; text-decoration:none; }
```

It works, but on smaller devices, like my phone, the popup doesn't scroll so I can't see all of the content or get to the button to close it. I've been trying different things with no luck so far. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I see you have assigned `display: block` to following element:
`<div class="popup" style="display: block;">`. Please try changing it as :

`<div class="popup" style="display: contents;">`

Comment: I tried that, but instead of the popup appearing on top of the page elements, it now appears between them: https://cismiami.org/index4.html